# How to Join two Custom fields values and save to third field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, wordpress-hook

i am trying to join two custom fields and save the combined value to the third custom field.

first custom field have some options like state abbreviation(meta key='state_found') drop down and second custom field is generating random numbers, following is the code for random number which is saved to Post random(Meta key='post_random')

```
function get_post_random_wpse( $post_id = 0, $meta_key = 
'post_random',$meta_value = 0 )
{
if( ! ( $post_id > 0 && strlen( $meta_key ) > 0 ) )
return 0;
if( '' === ( $post_rand = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ) ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $post_rand = $meta_value);
return $post_rand;
}
```

i am trying to merge these two fields with this code

```
add_filter('save_post', 'combine_my_fields');
function combine_my_fields($post_id, $post) {
$sup = get_post_meta($post_id, 'state_found', true);
$sup = ', ' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_random', true);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'new_id', $sup);
}
```

the final value must be saved into New ID(meta key='new_id')

but i don't know why the thing is not working the random code is generating perfectly but the values don't get merged and one more thing i want to make sure all the random numbers must be unique.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('save_post', 'combine_my_fields');

function combine_my_fields($post_id) {
    $sup = get_post_meta($post_id, 'state_found','test text added');
    $sup.= ', ' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_random', 'test text added');
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'new_id', $sup);
}
```

Comment: @VikasGaur Test my updated code let me know how it goes

Comment: its working but i have to update post again to get these combined values in  'new_id' and there is a comma and space between first value and second value
Thanks

Comment: I fixed the comma and space issue but i dont want to update post after publish new id must be inserted at post creation is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Hi,
I tried both the solutions you guys provided both the solution is combining the custom fields but not on publishing the post but if i update post after publish then i get a combined value i think its due to the random number is generating on the post publish and it should be generate before publishing post let me know if i am right or wrong because i can't figure out a way to generate  random number before post is published

Thanks